# How was the derivative of this function found?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

We have the following function:

[image]

We want the partial derivative with sigma square as our variable.

[image]

I understand how we got the left part which is this:

[image]

But I don't see how we obtained the rest. Which derivation rules where used? 
BTW we want the maximum that's why the function is made = 0 in our case.

I also forgot to add that because sigma square is our variable you should see it as if it was variable and note (variable)^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, factor out the $1\over \sigma^2$ from the sum.

$$\dfrac{d}{d\sigma^2} \dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} = -\dfrac{1}{(\sigma^2)^2}$$

is just the power rule $\dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{1}{x}=-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$. The rest of the sum is constant w.r.t. $\sigma^2$.

Comment: What happened to the logarithm in $\log(\sigma^2)$?  It just uses $\frac{d\log x}{dx}=\frac1x$ with $x=\sigma^2$

Comment: The're taking the derivative of the RHS and setting it to 0